# What's the difference between TakeLargestBy and MaximalBy?

Tags: functions

I find most examples in doc of `MaximalBy` can be replaced by `TakeLargestBy`, and the result is the same.

[image]

```
MaximalBy[{e1,e2,e3},f] == TakeLargestBy[{e1,e2,e3},f,1]

MaximalBy[{e1,e2,e3},f,n] == TakeLargestBy[{e1,e2,e3},f,n]

MaximalBy[f] == TakeLargestBy[f,1]
```

Just in this case they have difference,`TakeLargestBy` will drop Null,None,Indeterminate,Missing. And the order of element returned by these two functions is not the same.

So what the purpose of design these two functions,it looks do the same thing.

Comment: Because they don't "do the same thing". Have you read the documentation at all? Try, e.g., TakeLargestBy[s, #^2 &, 5] and MaximalBy[s, #^2 &, 5] with s={-7, -10, 7, -8, 6}

Comment: `TakeLargestBy` sorts the e_i by numerical magnitude. `MaximalBy` return the maximal e_i are returned in the order they appear in the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know of two differences between `MaximalBy` and `TakeLargestBy` -- there may more I am not aware of.

1. `MaximalBy[data, f, n]` is equivalent to `Take[SortBy[data, OrderedQ /* f], -n]` while `TakeLargestBy[data, f, n]` is equivalent to `Take[SortBy[data, N /* f], -n]`
2. The argument `n` is optional in `MaximalBy[data, f, n]` and defaults to 1 while it is required in `TakeLargestBy[data, f, n]`

The first difference will not matter if all the elements in `list` satisfy `NumberQ`, but may give unexpected results from `MaximalBy` when one or more elements only satisfy the weaker predicate `NumericQ`.  For example (taken from section Possible Issues of in the article [ref/MaximalBy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html),

```
data = {BesselJ[0, 1], BesselJ[1, 1]};
N @ data
```

> `{0.765198, 0.440051}`

```
MaximalBy[data, Identity, 1]
```

> `{BesselJ[1, 1]} (* which is smaller than`BesselJ[0, 1] *)`

However, `TakeLargestBy` gets it right.

```
TakeLargestBy[data, Identity, 1]
```

> `{BesselJ[0, 1]}`